# How to syntax Locating by XPath in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

i am having trouble to access a text field in this long path of frames, tabels, tr, td. Please see bottom line of screenshot.
Can someone give a hint on how the syntax in this case should be?
Is there a better way of doing this rathen then inspect in chrome?

I have to find a field and insert text into it.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGsZ8.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code to locate the desired element and to send text into it:

```
# get element  after explicitly waiting for 10 seconds
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='IX_SEARCH_VALUE_2']")))
# input the text here
element.send_keys("enter the text here")
```

You will need below import statement:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

I do not see any `iframe` in the screenshot you have provided. If in case an `iframe` exist, first switch to the `iframe` within which the element is located, and then perform action.

Example code to switch into an `iframe`:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='iframe']")))
```

Answer (score 0):

To find element by XPATH with selenium, use [find_element](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("google.com") #replace with your url

my_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='IX_SEARCH_VALUE_2']")

print(my_element.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The css is input[name='IX_SEARCH_VALUE_2']

Answer (score 0):

```
iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/frameset/frameset/frameset/frame[3]")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

I had to switch to the frame at first.
by the way, `selectorshub` is a very nice plugin. On top of the inspector in chrome